# Datatype casting in c++

Tags: c++, casting

I've been using casting a lot recently, but i don't actually know what some of the cast do. This might be some pretty basic stuff, but i just don't get it.

What are the differences in these?

```
*(DWORD*)VAR;
(DWORD)VAR;// changes VAR to DWORD
(DWORD*)VAR;//Changes pointer VAR to DWORD
(DWORD)*VAR;//Changes pointer VAR to DWORD
```

According to MSDN

```
const char *pCast = myStr; // or (const char *)myStr;
(DWORD*)VAR is the same as DWORD *VAR which is also the same as (DWORD)*VAR
```

Comment: Google links appreciated as well,

Comment: the stuff inside the parenthesis is the type you are casting to. unary * is dereference.

Comment: Yes that is what my question is about @sp2danny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `*(DWORD*)VAR;` cast `VAR` to a pointer to a `DWORD` and return the value stored there.
- `(DWORD*)VAR;` cast `VAR` to a pointer to a `DWORD`.
- `(DWORD)VAR;` cast `VAR` to a `DWORD`.
- `(DWORD)*VAR;` assumes `VAR` is a pointer, retrieves the value stored there and casts the value to a `DWORD`.

Answer (score 0):

Read them right to left

`*(DWORD*)VAR;` 
- read `VAR` (should be a pointer) 
- cast to "pointer to unsigned long" 
- dereference (result is unsigned long lvalue)

`(DWORD*)VAR;` 
- read `VAR` (should be a pointer) 
- cast to "pointer to unsigned long" (result is unsigned long pointer)

`(DWORD)VAR;` 
- read `VAR` 
- cast to "unsigned long" (result is unsigned long rvalue)

`(DWORD)*VAR;` 
- read `VAR` (should be a pointer) 
- dereference 
- cast to "unsigned long" (result is unsigned long rvalue)